# x64 LAR instruction (Load Access Rights Byte)

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, x86-64, machine-code

This instruction has some confusing modes, here's the table for the 64-bit version on page 862 of the intel x64 manual:

```
Opcode    Instruction         Description
0F 02 /r  LAR r16, r16/m16    r16 ← access rights referenced by r16/m16
0F 02 /r  LAR reg, r32/m16    reg ← access rights referenced by r32/m16
```

What size register is that 'reg'?  Is this an instruction that needs the 16-bit 66H prefix?  Or a 67H or REX.W prefix maybe? I assume it needs a prefix because the op-codes are the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMD documentation is a bit clearer about that :

```
LAR reg16, reg/mem16        0F 02 /r        ...
LAR reg32, reg/mem16        0F 02 /r        ...
LAR reg64, reg/mem16        0F 02 /r        ...
```

```
reg/mem16 : Word (16-bit) operand in a GPR register or memory.
```

And also :

> In 64-bit mode, most instructions default to a 32-bit operand size. For these instructions, a REX prefix
>   (page 14) can specify a 64-bit operand size, and a 66h prefix specifies a 16-bit operand size. The REX
>   prefix takes precedence over the 66h prefix.

Quotes from *AMD64 Architecture
Programmer’s Manual
Volume 3:
General-Purpose and
System Instructions*

Comment: Is that 'reg/mem16' always a 16-bit register?  The intel reference lists it as both r16 and r32...

Comment: @RyanBrown On the AMD doc, it's always 16-bit. The Intel one mention on the little note that "_only bits 16-0 are used. Other bits are ignored_", so it would mean 32-bit is accepted but useless. Also, I often use [this](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) for quick tests (not 100% reliable but handy), and it seems to force 16-bit.